# Android - Preview video captured with custom camera in VideoView before saving it

Tags: java, android, video, camera, android-videoview

I am recording 20 max seconds videos in my Android app with a custom camera.
I would like to preview automatically the recorded video before saving it (on the phone or on a server). I know I have to use a VideoView but I can't find how.

I would like to stop the recording if it exceed 20 seconds and launch automatically the preview (VideoView) or when the user stops the capture sooner.
With 2 buttons "Delete" and "OK".

Anyone knows how to do it? Do I have to create a new activity and using an intent?

Here is the current code which record the video :

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    // 1. Open Camera     
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
    //Set video duration to 20 seconds max
    int clipsDuration = 20000;
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(clipsDuration);

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    } else { 
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    }

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you so much for you help !

Comment: "before saving it (on the phone or on a server)" -- you are already saving it on the phone.

Comment: I know. :)
But now I want to add a step before saving it (or not) which will allow me to preview the video I just recorded (thanks to VideoView apparently) and then decide to save the video or not.

Comment: "But now I want to add a step before saving it" -- I am not aware that `MediaRecorder` supports recording to memory. I am also uncertain if you have heap space for 20 seconds of video. I also do not know if there would be a good way to get `VideoView` to play from memory. What is your particular problem with having the video on disk, then deleting the file if the user elects not to keep it?

Comment: Good point :)  Thank you for your anwers.
I thought about this idea but I was afraid it would take too much time.
Moreover in the end I want to send the video on a server and not storing it on the users' phone.
How apps like Snapchat for instance handle the video preview before to send it?... Because it's the same use case.

Comment: "How apps like Snapchat for instance handle the video preview before to send it?" -- since I didn't write Snapchat, I have no idea, sorry.